# Statistic Calculations in laravel

Tags: class, statistics, laravel-5

I'm working on a project for golfstatistics. Right now I made it so far to enter and edit golfstatistics. I'm working with laravel 5 btw.

My database schema works like this:

- Every round you play saves one entry in the round table with information like (date, playid, weather, courseid)
- for every hole played an entry in the score table is made. There I have a reference to the roundid and information like (score, fairwayhit, greenhit, putts, penalties, ....)

No I want to create reports where I can filter for date and course etc.
What I did for now is. I created a Statistic class where I can pass the date, playerid, roundid, courseid in the construct. The construct will query all the rounds played, matching those filters.

Then, foreach statistic I made a public function ex. scoring_average, greenhit_percantage, putts_per_round, putts_per_greeninregulation etc. there are about 15 stats.

So my question is: is that right what I'm doing here? because I have about 15 functions just to calculate statistics.

Please give me some advice if you have a better solution.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

class Statistic {

```
/**
 * The table associated with the model.
 *
 * @var string
 */
public $rounds = [];

public function __construct($user_id, $roundid = null, $start = "2000-01-01", $end = "2030-01-01", $courseid = 0){
    $this->rounds = Round::where('user_id', '=', $user_id)->get();
}

public function score(){
    if(count($this->rounds) > 0){
        $avg = 0;
        foreach($this->rounds as $round){
            $scores = Score::where('round_id', '=', $round->id)->get(['score']);
            foreach($scores as $score){
                $avg += $score->score;
            }
        }

        return $avg / count($this->rounds);
    } else {
        return "N/A";
    }

}

public function fir(){
    if(count($this->rounds) > 0){
        $fairway = [];
        foreach($this->rounds as $round){
            $scores = Score::where('round_id', '=', $round->id)->get(['fir']);
            foreach($scores as $score){
                if($score->fir != 0){
                    array_push($fairway, $score->fir);
                }

            }
        }

        $hits = array_count_values($fairway);

        //unset($hits[0]); //unsets par 3 with value 0

        return self::percArray($hits);

        return $perc;
    } else {
        return "N/A";
    }

}
```